# open files in sorted order (OSX)

Tags: macos, mac, command-line, bash, sorting

I'm looking for a terminal command to open many files in preview in "sorted" order.  I'd like to open the files in order: 1.pdf, 2.pdf, 3.pdf, 4.pdf, etc.  But without first sorting, they are opened in order:  1.pdf, 10.pdf, 11.pdf,...2.pdf, 20.pdf, etc.

The command:

```
ls | sort -n
```

writes them to the terminal window in the correct order, but I can't pipe that to the "open" command (osx).  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`xargs`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xargs.1.html) command is useful here:

```
ls | sort -n | xargs open
```

`xargs` will read filenames from stdin and pass them as arguments to `open`

Comment: This is great, but Preview still applies the filesystem sort order which is annoying.